# What is the significance of the median eigenvalue of a graph Laplacian?

Tags: graph-theory, matrix-analysis, eigenvalues, laplacian

<sub>[Crossposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/978431) on Mathematics SE</sub>

---

When I look at the spectral density plots of my (usual) Laplacian graphs, they spike at the median eigenvalue. But what significance for the graph/matrix (which originates from a network) does the median eigenvalue hold? Are there any generalizations that can be made about the median eigenvalue?

Googling "median eigenvalue" turns up work by Bohar, which is quite opaque and focused specifically on molecular orbits. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Depending on the size of your graph, for large number of vertices you're probably seeing a semicircle distribution of eigenvalues?

Comment: More scale-free (barabasi-albert) distribution.

Comment: Do you mean “Bojan Mohar” when you write “Bohar”?